# Is indenting related elements in CSS a good coding convention?

Tags: css

Is indenting code like this a good coding convention for CSS?

```
       .bg-twitter {
          padding: 50px 0; }
          .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message {
            border: 2px solid #eee;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            display: block;
            color: #222; }
            .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:hover, .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:focus, .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:active {
              border-color: #0C518A;
              text-decoration: none; }
            .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:focus {
              border-color: #999; }
          .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span {
            text-align: center;
            display: inherit; }
            .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:hover, .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:focus, .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:active {
              border-color: #0C518A;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-weight: 400; }
```

Otherwise, should it be just going to straight down?

Comment: This is entirely personal preference, and you'll find arguments on both sides of the fence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you think, which code is more ease to read? Use less or sass to write really pretty code :)

```
   .bg-twitter {
       padding: 50px 0;
   }
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message {
       border: 2px solid #eee;
       padding: 10px;
       margin: 10px;
       display: block;
       color: #222;
   }
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:hover,
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:focus,
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:active {
       border-color: #0C518A;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter .twitter-message:focus {
       border-color: #999;
   }
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span {
       text-align: center;
       display: inherit;
   }
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:hover,
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:focus,
   .bg-twitter .tile-twitter span a:active {
       border-color: #0C518A;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-weight: 400;
   }
```

Scss:

```
 .bg-twitter {
     padding: 50px 0;

     .tile-twitter {
         .twitter-message {
             border: 2px solid #eee;
             padding: 10px;
             margin: 10px;
             display: block;
             color: #222;

             &:hover, 
             &:focus, 
             &:active {
                 border-color: #0C518A;
                 text-decoration: none;
             }

             &:focus {
                 border-color: #999;
             }
         }

         span {
             text-align: center;
             display: inherit;

             a {
                 &:hover, 
                 &:focus, 
                 &:active {
                     border-color: #0C518A;
                     text-decoration: none;
                     font-weight: 400;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```